# Add a CSS framework to Angular vendor bundle

Tags: css, angular, webpack

## Here is my situation :

- Web site powered by [Angular 4](https://angular.io)
- Initialised with [Angular Starter Kit](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter)
- Using [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/) as CSS framework

## Here is my issue :

Adding [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/) to webpack has no effect.

## Here is what I tried :

(I followed the [official Angular documentation for webpack](https://angular.io/guide/webpack))

Add *semantic-ui* to `package.json` from terminal

```
npm install semantic-ui-css --save
```

Add *vendor* bundle to the *entry* property in `webpack.common.js`

```
[...]
entry: {

  'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
  'main':      AOT ? './src/main.browser.aot.ts' :
              './src/main.browser.ts',
  'vendor':   './src/vendor.ts'

},
[...]
```

Create the `src/vendor.ts` file and set its content to :

```
// Angular
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';
import '@angular/http';
import '@angular/router';

// My CSS framework
import 'semantic-ui-css';
```

## What I got :

Webpack build without error, the vendor bundle is created :
`vendor.bundle.js   3.74 MB       2  [emitted]  [big]  vendor`

And webpack inject the bundle script in the HTML page :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js" async></script></body>
```

But the visual doesn't change (but should I check it with CDN) and I don't see the `vendor.bundle.js` file in the `dist` folder.

I probably miss something, what is it ?

Answer (score 1):

> Below statement only imports semantic.js as package.json is pointing
>   to that file.

```
import 'semantic-ui-css';
```

To import CSS, you can add the below:

```
// To import CSS
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.css';
```

OR in **src/styles/styles.scss**

```
@import '../../node_modules/semantic-ui-css/semantic.css';
```

Comment: The first solution (with **vendor.ts**) add semantic CSS code to the vendor bundle, I can see it when I open the compiled file. But the CSS is not enable like expected. Do you know why ?

While your second solution (with **styles.scss**) works perfectly. But the semantic CSS is not in the vendor bundle, the code is inside the main bundle instead. This is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well in fact the second solution doesn't work so well, the semantic javascript is not loaded.

Comment: Yes, in the first case it will be a part of main bundle, but you can enable a separate css file using ExtractTextPlugin configuration.
In 2nd solution, hope you are including Javascript and CSS both?

Comment: Yes I include JS and CSS in the bundle. I don't understand where my mistake is.